# Why does this typescript typeguard not work

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have the following code

```
const validProtocols = ["https", "http"] as const
type AllProtocols = typeof validProtocols
type Protocol = AllProtocols[number]
function isProtocol(p:unknown): p is Protocol{
  return typeof p === "string" && p in validProtocols
}

let parse = (p:string)=>{
  if(isProtocol(p))
    return p
  else
    throw `${p} is not a protocol`
}

console.log(parse("https"))
```

The code compiles but the final line throws as `isProtocol(p)` is returning false. What is wrong?

The code is to be used for validating input outside the control of the compiler ie: environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator checks whether a *property* exists on an object. For example:

```js
const obj = { prop: 'val' };
const arr = ['val'];

console.log('prop' in obj, 0 in arr);
```

It doesn't check *values*, only *properties*. To check values in an array, use `.includes` (and you'll also have to work around the [ugly type rules for `.includes`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) that make these sorts of checks much messier than one would expect):

```
function isProtocol(p:unknown): p is Protocol{
  return typeof p === "string" && (validProtocols as unknown as Array<string>).includes(p)
}
```

Comment: Why the typecast? validProtocols is string array no?

Comment: It's more specific than that - it's typed as `["https", "http"]`, and unfortunately TypeScript does not permit `.includes` to be called with elements that might not exist in the array. Many disagree with the design decision, so for now, to perform such a check, you'll need a workaround like the ugly type assertion in the answer.

Comment: Ok it's the ``as const`` More info is here. https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/ Thanks for the info.